# R returns incorrect answers for logical operations?

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a dataframe based on values in a single column (Column_A), using code similar to the following:

`new_df <- subset(df, df$Column_A<4)`

I noticed that this code returns all rows where the value for Column_A is less than 4...as well as one row where the value is **12.4** (so, *greater* than 4).

I tried to look more closely at what R believes the value of this cell to be--`df$Column_A[[2]]` returned the expected value of 12.4.

I then tested several other variants of this logical operation--e.g.`df$Column_A[[2]]<12` , `df$Column_A[[2]]<11` , `df$Column_A[[2]]<10` , `df$Column_A[[2]]<9`...

The first three expressions returned the expected answer ("FALSE"). However, `df$Column_A[[2]]<9` and all variants of this expression with lower values (e.g. <8, <7...) return the answer ("TRUE"). This is *clearly* incorrect.

I have no idea what is causing this and would really appreciate any insight.

Comment: Check the `class(df$Column_A)`. Is it numeric

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It could happen if the `class` of the column is `character`

```
"12.4" < 4
[1] TRUE
```

Remedy is to convert to `numeric` first and then subset

```
df$Column_A <- as.numeric(df$Column_A)
subset(df, Column_A < 4)
```